# jasmine sinon synchronous ajax call causes infinite loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, jasmine, synchronous, sinon

I'm using jasmine to do unit testing and sinon to mock an ajax call. However, this causes an infinite loop where my test case is called repeatedly. The ajax call is made synchronously. If I change the ajax call to be asynchronous, the infinite loop does not occur. Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the function with the ajax call:

```
define([
    // Utils
    'util/logging',
    // Project Dependencies
    'views/core/baseView',
    'i18n!i18n_DNA/nls/basePage',
    'i18n!i18n_DNA/nls/consentSettingsView',
    'duster!templates/widgets/testSettings/consentSettings.dust.html'
], function (Log, BaseView, i18n_basePage, i18n_consentSettingsView, template) {
    'use strict';

    // ConsentSettingsView
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    return BaseView.extend({

        events: {
            'click #deleteTestButton': 'deleteTestModal'
        },

        className: 'connectDelete',

        // initialize()
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        initialize: function () {

            this.hasConsented = this.options.hasConsented;
            this.testId = this.options.testId;
            this.appRouter = this.options.appRouter;

            // Call `super()`.
            BaseView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
        },

        // render()
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        render: function () {

            var self = this;

            var context = {
                i18n_basePage: i18n_basePage,
                i18n_consentSettingsView: i18n_consentSettingsView,
                hasConsented: this.hasConsented,
                testId: this.testId
            };

            dust.render('templates/widgets/testSettings/consentSettings.dust.html', context, function (err, out) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                } else {
                    self.$el.html(out);
                }
            });

            return self;
        },

        // deleteTestModal()
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        deleteTestModal: function () {
            AcomModal.open('deleteTestModal');
            $('#pDelId').click($.proxy( this.deleteTest, this));
        },

        // deleteTest()
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        deleteTest: function () {

            var self = this;

            $.ajax({
                url: 'testSettings/' + encodeURIComponent(this.testId),
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    password: $('#pUserPwd').val(),
                    testId: self.testId
                },
                async: false,
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    Log.info("Successfully deleted test #", self.testId, data, textStatus, jqXHR);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow) {
                    Log.error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow);

                    switch (jqXHR.status) {
                        case 401:
                            self.appRouter.navigate("#login", {trigger: true});
                            break;
                        case 404:
                            self.appRouter.navigate("#404", {trigger: true});
                            break;
                        default:
                            self.appRouter.navigate("#serviceUnavailable", {trigger: true});
                    }
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    $('#pDelId').unbind('click');
                    window.location = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my test case:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'views/widgets/testSettings/consentSettingsView'
], function (Backbone, ConsentSettingsView) {

    // deleteTestModal()
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    describe('ConsentSettingsView.deleteTest()', function () {

        var server;
        var appRouter;
        var consentSettingsView;

        // Setup
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        beforeEach(function(){

            appRouter = {
                navigate: function () {
                    console.log('navigate called', arguments);
                }
            };

            consentSettingsView = new ConsentSettingsView({
                hasConsented: false,
                testId: 1,
                appRouter: appRouter
            });

            server = sinon.fakeServer.create();

            server.respondWith(/testSettings\/(\d+)/, function(xhr, id) {
                switch (id) {
                    case '1':
                        xhr.respond(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, JSON.stringify({id: id, success: true}));
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        xhr.respond(401, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, JSON.stringify({id: id, success: false}));
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        xhr.respond(404, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, JSON.stringify({id: id, success: false}));
                        break;
                    default:
                        xhr.respond(500, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, JSON.stringify({id: id, success: false}));
                        break;
                }
            });
        });

        afterEach(function(){

            server.restore();
        });

        it('makes a successful ajax call', function () {

            consentSettingsView.testId = 1;
            consentSettingsView.deleteTest();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: As per skusunam's request, I tried to simply my project so he and others could reproduce it. I was not able to come up with a super simple test case. However, I did remove all the stuff not needed from my actual project, which you can download from here: 
http://www.lazyhsoftware.com/so/simple-test.zip  
To see the problem open src/test/js/jasmine/index.html in a browser such as chrome. You will have to have the "allow file access from files" option set, as in: --allow-file-access-from-files

Answer (score 0):

if you want a Async test, you need to use the Jasmine right way for async tests, they are different from sync, if you change your code now to async, it will return nothing, then you will expect strange behavior.

Take a look in: http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/#section-Asynchronous_Support

Now your test should be something like this:

```
    it('makes a successful ajax call', function () {
        runs(function() {
            consentSettingsView.testId = 1;
            consentSettingsView.deleteTest();
        });

        var timeoutIn = 1000; // A second
        waitFor(function() {
            // Return something that flags your test is ok or not after the timeout time
        }, 'No server response', timeoutIn);

        runs(function() {
            // Expected result to check from your test
        });
    });
```

Personal I think the better way to do this async test is change your method `deleteTest` to be able to pass a callback as argument like in `promisses` pattern:

```
deleteTest: function (success, fail) ....
```

Then you can type check and run in the desired context like this:

```
if (typeof success === 'function') { success.call(this); }
```

Same for fail, but inside the ajax failure callback function from jQuery options.

Now you can add to your test something like this:

```
    it('makes a successful ajax call', function () {
        var result = false;
        runs(function() {
            consentSettingsView.testId = 1;
            consentSettingsView.deleteTest(function () { 
                result = true;
            }, function () { 
                result = false; 
            });
        });

        var timeoutIn = 1000; // A second
        waitFor(function() {
            return result;
        }, 'No server response', timeoutIn);

        runs(function() {
            // Expected result to check from your test
            expect(result).toBe(true);
        });
    });
```

Posting looking in the google, I found this [article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/08/18/jasmine-async-making-asynchronous-testing-with-jasmine-suck-less/).

He explains very like I've done to you, hope that can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding to my question. However, my test is synchronous. What you have described and referenced are instructions for doing an asynchronous test.

Comment: Did you try to use async way testing, even setting up the ajax to synchronous? Sure, give a try, I think the loop bug will not happen.